# EditText horizontal line on center

Tags: android, layout

There is a grey line on the EditText's on On android 4.0.4 (Galaxy S3) You can see it at:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/c4xz2yjaw1fbamr/Screenshot_2012-10-10-11-59-29.png 
There is no problem with Galaxy S(Android 2.3.3) you can see at: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1l6a7u9f8ey7q76/device-2012-10-10-120640.png

I create them with the following code. I don't do anything about it on XML files. What could be wrong with it?

Thanks

```
        for (int i = 0; i < editTexts.length; i++) {

            EditText rowEditText = new EditText(getBaseContext());

            rowEditText.setSingleLine(true);
            rowEditText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            rowEditText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
            filters[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(10);
            rowEditText.setFilters(filters);    
            rowEditText.setHint((i + 1) + ".Oyuncu"); 

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int) (metrics.widthPixels * (0.6f)), (int) (metrics.heightPixels * (0.07f)));
            spinnerlayout.addView(rowEditText,layoutParams);
            editTexts[i] = rowEditText;


        }
```

Comment: possibly you are using 9 patches that are being scaled at compile time, resulting in a loss of black dots

Comment: I did  getBackground(). I get a 9 patch drawable but I don't set any background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
The code was like this:

```
      EditText rowEditText = new EditText(getBaseContext());
```

I changed to:

```
      EditText rowEditText = new EditText(Class.this);
```

Lesson learned: don't use getBaseContext() or getApplicationContext() in an activity